# how to make height of a div responsive?

Tags: html, css

I want a div where if the height of that div exceeds 450px there will be scroller. I am able to do that by adding a classname say, fixedScroll_450 to the div.

```
<div class="fixedScroll_450" id="content"></div>
```

Now the div's content will be generated dynamically, and if it exceeds 450px of height there will be scroller otherwise not. 
Now for the styling I add in the class

```
.fixedScroll_450{
   min-height: 450px;
   max-height: 450px;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

it is working fine.. But i want to give the height in percentage value not in pixel. But

```
 .fixedScroll_450{
   min-height: 30%;
   max-height: 30%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

is not working. the height set with 100% with this code. plz guide me..

Comment: Firstly there is no need for min-height css style and please set parent divs height as 450px then only height in % works.

Comment: Why do you want percentage? In other words, you want percentage of the height of what exactly? the parent DIV? the entire page? the browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vh` css unit for height like `max-height: 30vh`

```css
.fixedScroll_450{
   max-height: 30vh;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="fixedScroll_450" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed by setting the height on the html and body tag

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

In CSS thos two elements don't have a height set. So by using `min-height: 30%` the browser doesn't have a computed height. The moment you add some content, the height of the html and body tags grows with the content itself, not with the height of the page.

On the other hand, if you want to make sure that it is always 30% of the screen height, you can use `30vh` (30% of the viewport height). A further explanation of these units can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Answer (score 1):

you just need to set height through jquery like that.
remove the max-height through css and try it, i hope it should work

```
$('#content').css('height':$(window).height()+'px')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide height to the parent element it would take height of div tag `<div class="fixedScroll_450" id="content"></div>` based on the content it has. You need to provide some fixed height to either the parent element of this div tag in order for scroll bar to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit different of an approach. If you can use flexbox (see browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)) you could do it like this:

```css
.outer-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: #64b92a;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.fixedScroll_450{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fixedScroll_450">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```